# In Go, how to Unmarshal bson byte[] data into an array of structs?

Tags: database, go, struct, bson

What's the best way to `Unmarshal` **bson byte[]** data into an array of structs, when the array of structs is passed into an `interface{}` parameter?

For demonstration purposes, in the following code, I use `bson.Marshal()` on the `inStructArr` to get the `byte[]` type of data. This is so I can use `bson.Unmarshal(...)` to pipe into the `outStructArr`.

```
import "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"

type User struct {
    Name string
}

func DecodeArrData(inStructArr, outStructArr interface{}) {
    inStructArrData, _ := bson.Marshal(inStructArr)
    bson.Unmarshal(inStructArrData, outStructArr) // <-- Error happens here
    // What's the right way of accomplishing this?
}

func Main() {
    outUsers := &[]User{}
    inUsers := []User{User{"A"}, User{"B"}}

    DecodeArrData(inUsers, outUsers)
}
```

When I do this, the error-message I get is: `Unsupported document type for unmarshalling: []User`. What's the right way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Marshal` and `Unmarshal` functions work with BSON documents, not BSON arrays.

Wrap the slices in a struct to provide the document expected by the package:

```
func DecodeArrData(inStructArr, outStructArr interface{}) error {
    in := struct{ Data interface{} }{Data: inStructArr}
    inStructArrData, err := bson.Marshal(in)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var out struct{ Data bson.Raw }
    if err := bson.Unmarshal(inStructArrData, &out); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return out.Data.Unmarshal(outStructArr)
}
```

If you are willing to take advantage of an undocumented feature of the `Marshal` function and add some BSON format knowledge to your application, then you can omit the wrapper.

The undocumented feature of `Marshal` is that it encodes slices as BSON arrays. The BSON array can be decoded using a [bson.Raw](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Raw) value with Kind set the the BSON code for arrays (the value 4) and Data set to the array data:

```
func DecodeArrData(inStructArr, outStructArr interface{}) error {
    inStructArrData, err := bson.Marshal(inStructArr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    raw := bson.Raw{Kind: 4, Data: inStructArrData}
    return raw.Unmarshal(outStructArr)
}
```